# Casting VARCHAR as INT plus addition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with three columns

location (varchar)
category (int)
barcode (int)

I wish to UPDATE the table so that barcode = location (as an int) + 2406 where the category = 12 and varchar > 1 or < 96

I'm not sure of the correct syntax but experimentation so far indicated that casting varchar as unassigned may be correct?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps location shouldn't be varchar! Anyway, you're in luck because MySQL interprets a number added to a 'number' as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to advise without seeing your current effort but this should do the trick.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET
    barcode = CAST(location AS int) + 2406
    WHERE category = 12
        AND CAST(location AS int) > 1
        AND CAST(location AS int) < 96
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.  I could not get your solution to work initially, so i used 'AS UNSIGNED' instead of 'AS INT' which worked perfectly.